# How can I configure OpenBox session for opening files by mime type?

Tags: open-files, openbox, mime-types

I've started using OpenBox and I really like it.

But my **chromium opens everything with firefox**.

Is there any fix for that? I'm looking for most lightweight solution, but also with easy and fast configuration.

Comment: It is a chromium problem, I think, not an openbox one.

Comment: I think it's not chromium problem, because when i was running CrunchBang chromium worked fine. But now i'm using Arch.

Comment: It's an XDG thing. I'm pretty sure chromium uses `xdg-open` for things it doesn't handle internally. Never figured out how to configure that thing correctly...

Comment: @Mat Yep. It's true. So u can put it into an answer. I'll ask another question.

Comment: @MiroK: that's not an answer at all, just a beginning of a clue - and I just don't understand how you're supposed to configure xdg-* thingies, never get it to work properly myself... so I'd like to see a proper answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses `xdg-open` to open unknown files.
The problem with the `xdg-open` script is that tries to figure out which desktop environment you have.
It does this by checking

```
detectDE()
{
    if [ x"$KDE_FULL_SESSION" = x"true" ]; then DE=kde;
    elif [ x"$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" != x"" ]; then DE=gnome;
    elif xprop -root _DT_SAVE_MODE | grep ' = \"xfce4\"$' >/dev/null 2>&1; then DE=xfce;
    fi  
}
```

Since Openbox doesn't set any of these variables `$DE` is empty and a generic approach is used.

In version 1.0 of the `xdg-utils` the default behavior looks like this

```
open_generic()
{
    IFS=":"
    for browser in $BROWSER; do
        if [ x"$browser" != x"" ]; then

            browser_with_arg=`echo "$browser" | sed s#%s#"$1"#`

            if [ x"$browser_with_arg" = x"$browser" ]; then "$browser" "$1";
            else $browser_with_arg;
            fi  

            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then exit_success;
            fi  
        fi  
    done

    exit_failure_operation_impossible "no method available for opening '$1'"
}
```

You can see that it tries to open everything with `$BROWSER`.
When `$BROWSER` isn't set it will be set to `firefox:mozilla:netscape`.

So the problem is that ether you need to set a DE, which then leads to new problems (like programs which try to connect to the DE session) or you set your `$BROWSER` to something like `exo-open`, `gnome-open` or `kfmclient exec`.

A [new release](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.1.0-rc1/) of `xdg-open` seems to fix this, but it seems to take forever.